# Definition of GetHashCode() in C#

Tags: c#, hash, gethashcode, iequalitycomparer

`Dictionary` in C# uses GetHashCode() to retrieve hash code of a given key. I walk through whole of the `Dictionary Class`, but there is not any definition for `GetHashCode()` function. It is bothering me and I don't know how I can find definition of it in this class!

Assume I am using `Dictionary<int,int> a = new Dictionary<int,int>()`, now what is the hash code of a given key in this structure? (e.g. suppose this: `a.Add(123,43)`. what is the hash code of this key, if number of buckets being 50)

This is a part of `Insert()` function of `Dictionary class`.

```
private void Insert(TKey key, TValue value, bool add)
    {
        int freeList;
        if (key == null)
        {
            ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentNullException(ExceptionArgument.key);
        }
        if (this.buckets == null)
        {
            this.Initialize(0);
        }
        int num = this.comparer.GetHashCode(key) & 0x7fffffff;
        int index = num % this.buckets.Length;
```

Comment: What do you mean "hash code of a given key"?

Comment: Do you mean this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3893782/how-is-gethashcode-implemented-for-int32

Comment: I want know the algorithm that used for generating hash code of a given key. Now I am asking if that key is an integer, how it will calculate?

Comment: Then it'll be the hash code of the integer.

Comment: As usual, _"As we know,"_ is followed by a heap of mis-infomation. Anyway, Dictionary is consuming GetHashCode(), not defining it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GetHashCode` is implemented on your `TKey` type, not on the `Dictionary` class.

For [`int.GetHashCode()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.gethashcode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which your example uses, it's defined as:

```
public override int GetHashCode()
{
    return this;
}
```

*Number of backets* has nothing to do with the hashcode value.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't specify an `IEqualityComparer`, `Dictionary` uses `EqualityComparer<T>.Default`. This is a comparer that will just call `object.GetHashCode` on the given argument. So look at `Int32.GetHashCode`.