# Faster HashMap for sequential keys

Tags: performance, rust, hashmap

Initially I was very surprised to find out Rust's `HashMap`, even with the `FNV` hasher, was considerably slower than the equivalents in Java, .NET, PHP. I am talking about optimized **Release** mode, not Debug mode. I did some calculations and realized the timings in Java/.NET/PHP were suspiciously low. Then it hit me - even though I was testing with a big hash table (millions of entries), I was reading mostly sequential *key* values (like `14, 15, 16, ...`), which apparently resulted in *lots of* CPU cache hits, due to the way the standard hash tables (and hash-code functions for integers and short strings) in those languages are implementated, so that entries with nearby keys are usually located in nearby memory locations.

Rust's `HashMap`, on the other hand, uses the so called `SwissTable` implementation, which apparently distributes values differently. When I tested reading by random keys, everything fell into place - the "competitors" scored behind Rust.

So if we are in a situation where we need to perform lots of gets sequentially, for example iterating some DB IDs that are ordered and mostly sequential (with not too many gaps), is there a good Rust hash map implementation that can compete with Java's `HashMap` or .NET's `Dictionary`?

---

P.S. As requested in the comments, I paste an example here. I ran lots of tests, but here is a simple example that takes 75 ms in Rust (release mode) and 20 ms in Java:

In Rust:

```
let hm: FnvHashMap<i32, i32> = ...;  
// Start timer here
let mut sum: i64 = 0;
for i in 0..1_000_000 {
    if let Some(x) = hm.get(&i) {
        sum += *x as i64;
    }
}
println!("The sum is: {}", sum);
```

In Java:

```
Map<Integer, Integer> hm = ...;
// Start timer here
long sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 1_000_000; i++) {
    sum += hm.get(i);
}
```

With `HashMap<i32, i32>` and its default [`SipHash`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/hash/struct.SipHasher.html) hasher it took 190 ms. I know *why* it's slower than `FnvHashMap`. I'm just mentioning that for completeness.

Comment: If you need to read sequentially, [`BTreeMap`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.BTreeMap.html) is likely a better choice.

Comment: @mcarton this is not a "rant". I ran quite a few tests. But here is one example: with Java's `HashMap<Integer, Integer>` it took 20 ms to read 1 mln sequential values. The same operation with Rust's `HashMap<i32, i32>` took 190 ms. With `FnvHashMap<i32, i32>` it took 75 ms. With Rust's `BTreeMap<i32, i32>` it took 170 ms.

Comment: @mcarton Let me also add it's not a surprise `BTreeMap` is unlikely to help in the case I described, as that structure would often require reading from several distant locations in RAM. That has little to do with the language. Also, I have the feeling some people are way too quick to give negative feedback, as soon as they read something is slower in Rust. Believe it or not, Rust is not *always* faster than Java/.NET/PHP, even though it usually is. And understanding a language's weaknesses is important in being able to write efficient code, I believe.

Comment: With an example like yours, on my machine I get 35ms for Rust, and 12ms for C# on .NET 6 (can't be bothered setting up Java, it was faster to convert to C#). If [I change the Rust example a bit, because you don't need to iterate in order for that example, Rust goes to 8ms](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=e21466dfb41cb2e3dd7a2779258c4ee6).

Comment: This is using a default hashmap, which uses an overkill hash function. As far as I know, .NET's hash is much more basic by default.

Comment: Benchmarking a single data structure like a map isn't really interesting unless you've determined that it's the bottleneck and it isn't already fast enough.  As others have mentioned, Rust's `HashMap` is secure on untrusted data by default, whereas many other languages are not and code written in them will contain a vulnerability if used in this way.  Have you verified that this is the bottleneck in your case?

Comment: @mcarton It is understandable that your modified version that iterates the whole map will perform faster. But that's a totally different use case, which only happens to work the same in this particular artificial example. I am not sure, but I would guess the hasher  used won't have any (significant) impact on how whole-map-iteration performs.

Answer (score 20):

First, here is some runnable code to measure the efficiency of the different implementations:

```
use std::{collections::HashMap, time::Instant};

fn main() {
    let hm: HashMap<i32, i32> = (0..1_000_000).map(|i| (i, i)).collect();
    let t0 = Instant::now();
    let mut sum = 0;
    for i in 0..1_000_000 {
        if let Some(x) = hm.get(&i) {
            sum += x;
        }
    }
    let elapsed = t0.elapsed().as_secs_f64();
    println!("{} - The sum is: {}", elapsed, sum);
}
```

On the old desktop machine I'm writing this on, it reports 76 ms to run. Since the machine is 10+ years old, I find it baffling that your hardware would take 190 ms to run the same code, so I'm wondering how and what you're actually measuring. But let's ignore that and concentrate on the relative numbers.

When you care about hashmap efficiency in Rust, and when the keys don't come from an untrusted source, the first thing to try should always be to switch to a non-DOS-resistant hash function. One possibility is the FNV hash function from the [`fnv`](https://docs.rs/fnv/latest/fnv/) crate, which you can get by switching `HashMap` to `fnv::FnvHashMap`. That brings performance to 34 ms, i.e. a **2.2x speedup**.

If this is not enough, you can try the hash from the [`rustc-hash`](https://docs.rs/rustc-hash/latest/rustc_hash/) crate (almost the same as [`fxhash`](https://docs.rs/fxhash/latest/fxhash/), but [allegedly](https://nnethercote.github.io/perf-book/hashing.html) better maintained), which uses the same function as the Rust compiler, adapted from the hash used by Firefox. Not based on any formal analysis, it performs badly on hash function test suites, but is reported to consistently outperform FNV. That's confirmed on the above example, where switching from `FnvHashMap` to `rustc_hash::FxHashMap` drops the time to 28 ms, i.e. a **2.7x speedup** from the initial timing.

Finally, if you want to just imitate what C# and Java do, and could care less about certain patterns of inserted numbers leading to degraded performance, you can use the aptly-named [`nohash_hasher`](https://docs.rs/nohash-hasher/latest/nohash_hasher/) crate that gives you an identity hash. Changing `HashMap<i32, i32>` to `HashMap<i32, i32, nohash_hasher::BuildNoHashHasher<i32>>` drops the time to just under 4 ms, i.e. a whopping **19x speedup** from the initial timing.

Since you report the Java example to be 9.5x faster than Rust, a 19x speedup should make your code approximately twice as fast as Java.

Comment: Thanks! As always, your answers are very informative! I ran some [extended tests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70554376/15602349), based on those ideas and more specifically on `NoHashHasher`, which really seems to be closest to what Java and .NET do.

Answer (score 4):

I decided to run some more tests, based on the suggestions by user4815162342. This time I used another machine with Ubuntu 20.04.

### Rust code

```
println!("----- HashMap (with its default SipHash hasher) -----------");
let hm: HashMap<i32, i32> = (0..1_000_000).map(|i| (i, i)).collect();
for k in 0..6 {
    let t0 = Instant::now();
    let mut sum: i64 = 0;
    for i in 0..1_000_000 {
        if let Some(x) = hm.get(&i) {
            sum += *x as i64;
        }
    }
    let elapsed = t0.elapsed().as_secs_f64();
    println!("The sum is: {}. Time elapsed: {:.3} sec", sum, elapsed);
}

println!("----- FnvHashMap (fnv 1.0.7) ------------------------------");
let hm: FnvHashMap<i32, i32> = (0..1_000_000).map(|i| (i, i)).collect();
for k in 0..6 {
    let t0 = Instant::now();
    let mut sum: i64 = 0;
    for i in 0..1_000_000 {
        if let Some(x) = hm.get(&i) {
            sum += *x as i64;
        }
    }
    let elapsed = t0.elapsed().as_secs_f64();
    println!("The sum is: {}. Time elapsed: {:.3} sec", sum, elapsed);
}

println!("----- FxHashMap (rustc-hash 1.1.0) ------------------------");
let hm: FxHashMap<i32, i32> = (0..1_000_000).map(|i| (i, i)).collect();
for k in 0..6 {
    let t0 = Instant::now();
    let mut sum: i64 = 0;
    for i in 0..1_000_000 {
        if let Some(x) = hm.get(&i) {
            sum += *x as i64;
        }
    }
    let elapsed = t0.elapsed().as_secs_f64();
    println!("The sum is: {}. Time elapsed: {:.3} sec", sum, elapsed);
}

println!("----- HashMap/BuildNoHashHasher (nohash-hasher 0.2.0) -----");
let hm: HashMap<i32, i32, nohash_hasher::BuildNoHashHasher<i32>> = (0..1_000_000).map(|i| (i, i)).collect();
for k in 0..6 {
    let t0 = Instant::now();
    let mut sum: i64 = 0;
    for i in 0..1_000_000 {
        if let Some(x) = hm.get(&i) {
            sum += *x as i64;
        }
    }
    let elapsed = t0.elapsed().as_secs_f64();
    println!("The sum is: {}. Time elapsed: {:.3} sec", sum, elapsed);
}
```

BTW the last one can be replaced with this shorter type:

```
let hm: IntMap<i32, i32> = (0..1_000_000).map(|i| (i, i)).collect();
```

For those interested, this is [`IntMap`](https://docs.rs/nohash-hasher/0.2.0/nohash_hasher/type.IntMap.html)'s definition:

```
pub type IntMap<K, V> = std::collections::HashMap<K, V, BuildNoHashHasher<K>>;
```

### Java code

On the same machine I tested a Java example. I don't have a JVM installed on it, so I used a Docker image `adoptopenjdk/openjdk14` and directly pasted the code below in `jshell>` (not sure if that would hurt Java's timings). So this is the Java code:

```
Map<Integer, Integer> hm = new HashMap<>();
for (int i = 0; i < 1_000_000; i++) {
    hm.put(i, i);
}
for (int k = 0; k < 6; k++) {
    long t0 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    // Start timer here
    long sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 1_000_000; i++) {
        sum += hm.get(i);
    }
    System.out.println("The sum is: " + sum + ". Time elapsed: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - t0) + " ms");
}
```

### Results

Rust (release mode):

```
----- HashMap (with its default SipHash hasher) -----------
The sum is: 499999500000. Time elapsed: 0.149 sec
The sum is: 499999500000. Time elapsed: 0.140 sec
The sum is: 499999500000. Time elapsed: 0.167 sec
The sum is: 499999500000. Time elapsed: 0.150 sec
The sum is: 499999500000. Time elapsed: 0.261 sec
The sum is: 499999500000. Time elapsed: 0.189 sec
----- FnvHashMap (fnv 1.0.7) ------------------------------
The sum is: 499999500000. Time elapsed: 0.055 sec
The sum is: 499999500000. Time elapsed: 0.052 sec
The sum is: 499999500000. Time elapsed: 0.053 sec
The sum is: 499999500000. Time elapsed: 0.058 sec
The sum is: 499999500000. Time elapsed: 0.051 sec
The sum is: 499999500000. Time elapsed: 0.056 sec
----- FxHashMap (rustc-hash 1.1.0) ------------------------
The sum is: 499999500000. Time elapsed: 0.039 sec
The sum is: 499999500000. Time elapsed: 0.076 sec
The sum is: 499999500000. Time elapsed: 0.064 sec
The sum is: 499999500000. Time elapsed: 0.048 sec
The sum is: 499999500000. Time elapsed: 0.057 sec
The sum is: 499999500000. Time elapsed: 0.061 sec
----- HashMap/BuildNoHashHasher (nohash-hasher 0.2.0) -----
The sum is: 499999500000. Time elapsed: 0.004 sec
The sum is: 499999500000. Time elapsed: 0.003 sec
The sum is: 499999500000. Time elapsed: 0.003 sec
The sum is: 499999500000. Time elapsed: 0.003 sec
The sum is: 499999500000. Time elapsed: 0.003 sec
The sum is: 499999500000. Time elapsed: 0.003 sec
```

Java:

```
The sum is: 499999500000. Time elapsed: 49 ms  // see notes below
The sum is: 499999500000. Time elapsed: 41 ms  // see notes below
The sum is: 499999500000. Time elapsed: 18 ms
The sum is: 499999500000. Time elapsed: 29 ms
The sum is: 499999500000. Time elapsed: 19 ms
The sum is: 499999500000. Time elapsed: 23 ms
```

*(With Java the first 1-2 runs are normally slower, as the JVM HotSpot still hasn't fully optimized the relevant piece of code.)*

Comment: Out of curiosity, are you running all that on a physical machine or a virtual one? I find the initial timing suspiciously slow. Also, is it with a recent Rust?

Comment: @user4815162342 The timings in this post are from a relatively cheap cloud VM and I used `rustc 1.59.0-nightly`. The previous timings mentioned were on a *very* cheap VM. I mostly cared about the relative difference, not absolute values.

Comment: I also got curious and decided to run the same tests on a VBox VM (Ubuntu 20.04) on my desktop PC. Tests ran roughly twice as fast (the `NoHashHasher`/`IntMap` less than twice, but still faster than on the cloud VM). I generally prefer to test performance on cloud VMs than VBox VMs, as that's closer to the real environment I'm using on prod.

Comment: I now ran the tests on another cloud provider and got results, similar to those on my VBox VM (Java times were ~16 ms, which was slightly slower than on my VBox env). This time I also ran the Java test w/o Docker, on a normally installed `java 17.0.1 2021-10-19 LTS` - no significant difference compared to the Docker-based.

Answer (score 2):

Rust's `HashMap` by default uses an implementation of [SipHash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SipHash) as the hash function. SipHash is designed to avoid denial-of-service attacks based on predicting hash collisions, which is an important security property for a hash function used in a hash map.

If you don't need this guarantee, you can use a simpler hash function. One option is using the [`fxhash` crate](https://crates.io/crates/fxhash), which should speed up reading integers from a `HashMap<i32, i32>` by about a factor of 3.

Other options are implementing your own trivial hash function (e.g. by simply using the identity function, which is a decent hash function for mostly consecutive keys), or using a vector instead of a hash map.

[.NET uses the identity function for hashes of `Int32` by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3893782/how-is-gethashcode-implemented-for-int32), so it's not resistant to hash flooding attacks. Of course this is faster, but the downside is not even mentioned in the [documentation of `Dictionary`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=net-6.0). For what it's worth, I prefer Rust's "safe by default" approach over .NET's any day, since many developers aren't even aware of the problems predictable hash functions can cause. Rust still allows you to use a more performant hash function if you don't need the hash flooding protection, so to me personally this seems to be a strength of Rust compared to at least .NET rather than a weakness.

Comment: "many developers aren't even aware of the problems predictable hash functions can cause" – Really? Even after very public flood of HashDoS vulnerabilities in Ruby, Python, Perl, PHP, Java, .NET, V8 / Node.JS, etc. in 2011 which got worldwide media attention? That is shocking.

Comment: Yes @JörgWMittag. Not shocking at all. Since 2011 up to the time that you wrote your comment, the total population of developers in the world has more than doubled. (Robert C. Martin said several years ago it doubles every 5 years.) New brains to development do not know what happened in 2011.

Even developers like myself at the time who were fighting the whirlwind of life might not have been paying close enough attention to remember and make the connection.

Answer (score 1):

Try [hashbrown](https://github.com/rust-lang/hashbrown)

It uses [aHash](https://github.com/tkaitchuck/aHash) which have full comparison with other HashMap algorithm [here](https://github.com/tkaitchuck/aHash/blob/master/compare/readme.md)

Comment: aHash is still DOS-resistant, though, so it can't compete with .NET/Java's identity hash function. For example, using aHash on the snippet from my answer (with the stdlib hashmap, wrapped as `ahash::HashMap<i32, i32>`) results in only a very modest 1.13x speedup. Using hashbrown directly results in a 2.14x speedup - better, but still not comparable to the 19x speedup when the integer value is just used directly.