# Rust function as slow as its python counterpart

Tags: python, rust

I am trying to speed up Python programs using Rust, a language in which I am a total beginner. I wrote a function that counts the occurrences of each possible string of length `n` within a larger string. For instance, if the main string is `"AAAAT"` and `n=3`, the outcome would be a hashmap `{"AAA":2,"AAT":1}`. I use pyo3 to call the Rust function from Python. The code of the Rust function is:

```rust
fn count_nmers(seq: &str, n: usize) -> PyResult<HashMap<&str,u64>> {
    let mut current_pos: usize = 0;
    let mut counts: HashMap<&str,u64> = HashMap::new();
    while current_pos+n <= seq.len() {
        //print!("{}\n", &seq[current_pos..current_pos+n]);
        match counts.get(&seq[current_pos..current_pos+n]) {
            Some(repeats) => counts.insert(&seq[current_pos..current_pos+n],repeats+1),
            None => counts.insert(&seq[current_pos..current_pos+n],1)
        };
        current_pos +=1;
    }
    //print!("{:?}",counts)
    Ok(counts)
}
```

When I use small values for `n` (`n<10`), Rust is about an order of magnitude faster than Python, but as the length of n increases, the gap tends to zero with both functions having the same speed by `n=200`. (see graph)
[Times to count for different n-mer lengths (Python black, rust red)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z3p7w.png)

I must be doing something wrong with the strings, but I can't find the mistake.

---

The python code is:

```py
def nmer_freq_table(sequence,nmer_length=6):
    nmer_dict=dict()
    for nmer in seq_win(sequence,window_size=nmer_length):
        if str(nmer) in nmer_dict.keys():
            nmer_dict[str(nmer)]=nmer_dict[str(nmer)]+1
        else:
            nmer_dict[str(nmer)]=1
    return nmer_dict

def seq_win(seq,window_size=2):
    length=len(seq)
    i=0
    while i+window_size <= length:
        yield seq[i:i+window_size]
        i+=1
```

[image: benchmark results graph]

Comment: Why do you expect Rust to be faster at that? And what are the Python codes?

Comment: Rust is a compiled language. Did you turn optimizations on and make sure you're in release mode? Benchmarking is meaningless in debug mode

Comment: @KellyBundy Well, as much as I love Python, it is supposed to be slower. And for the small substrings it is indeed an order of magnitude slower.

Comment: Yes, I compiled using cargo compile --release. The difference with the debug-unoptimized version is not that big, though.

Comment: Two things: One, using the [`Entry` api](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/hash_map/struct.HashMap.html#method.entry) should cut down on memory accesses, and two, your Rust code could panic on arbitrary utf-8 strings. And just because something is compiled doesn't make it magically faster. This is almost exclusively random memory accesses, I don't see why Rust should be significantly faster at that than Python.

Comment: @isaactfa So the access to the HashMap is basically the bottleneck here and there is not much that we can do to speed it up...

Comment: But with Python, the actual work is still done in C (assuming you use CPython), and when you make n larger, the fraction of the time spent on interpreting Python shrinks. With sufficiently large n, you're essentially *only* measuring its C speed, not its Python speed.

Comment: @AlbertoMarinSanguino That seems to be more or less the case here. Have you profiled your code and determined this function to be a bottleneck? This task should be parallelizable quite nicely, maybe that could speed it up.

Comment: What happens with n larger than 200? Does Python become *faster* or do both remain equally fast?

Comment: @KellyBundy Added longer n values to the benchmark. It seems the speedup is minimized exactly for the n i need :-)

Comment: The Python code could btw also be quite a bit better: [code](https://tio.run/##XY7BDoIwDEDv@4re2AIeDIkxJB6Mv@DNGIKjgyXQjVIOfj0iUWJ819fXNj6lDZQfI8@z49CDDV2HVnygEXwfAwtcwkSCrFSNDqhHLh3jUEr16FCPOExIFrNVdEiNtKeDKRQsMMrEBLW3oj9b9CrefMubhwJ8@tPftxkXGDx4Aq6oQb3o7aCBHfw0kMLerJ0xSkX2JPr/1@S8cE0yyI2Z5xc)

Comment: @KellyBundy You are absolutely right. I just have a lot of functions that work on a sliding window and never thought of optimizing them until now. With your answers and a few others, I start to see when to optimize my python code and when to go for a compiled language.

Comment: @isaactfa I am still at the "Hello world!" stage with Rust, parallelizing is why I want to learn Rust, but I am not there yet.

Comment: @AlbertoMarinSanguino Then optimization is the last thing I'd worry about.

Comment: @isaactfa Sure, I was just surprised by the similar performance of both functions. Specially because, as Kelly said, the Python code was not written to be particularly fast.

Comment: Also, look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70551997/faster-hashmap-for-sequential-keys. It behaves different if keys are sequential or

Comment: Python's performance increase over the n-mer length range of [350, 400] is interesting.

Comment: @SargeATM Looks like it happened to be unusually slow at 350 once, maybe the machine was busy with other stuff for a moment. That bump doesn't appear in either Python version in the updated plot.

Comment: @SargeATM Yeah, I am only running things once for each plot. All functions seem to have more or less the same speed except for Kelly´s Python version that is consistently faster.

Comment: Btw I only converted the Counter to dict in order to match the original. If you're ok with a Counter, leaving that conversion out saves about 15% at n=200 in my test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are computing hash function multiple times, this may matter for large n values. Try using [entry](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html#method.entry) function instead of manual inserts:

```rust
while current_pos+n <= seq.len() {
    let en = counts.entry(&seq[current_pos..current_pos+n]).or_default();
    *en += 1;
    current_pos +=1;
}
```

[Complete code here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=6ccea97ffdc295c7df1b09e4b31d9640)

Next, make sure you are running `--release` compiled code like `cargo run --release`.

And one more thing to take in mind is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70551997/faster-hashmap-for-sequential-keys), Rust may use non-optimal hash function for your case which you can change.

And finally, on large data, most of time is spent in HashMap/dict internals which are not a python, but compiled code. So don't expect it to scale well.

Comment: Also Python caches string hash values which would explain its shallower slope on the performance graph compared to Rust. "The performance of hash algorithm shouldn't affect general benchmarks since _hash value is cached inside string object_." https://bugs.python.org/issue29410

Comment: Interestingly Python and Rust use the same hash algorithm, SipHash 1-3.

Answer (score 2):

Could it be because as n gets larger the number of iterations through the loop gets smaller?

Fewer iterations through the loop would reduce the performance gain seen by using Rust. I'm sure there is a small per function call performance cost for transition/marshaling to Rust from Python. This would explain how eventually the performance from pure Python and Python/Rust becomes the same.

Comment: This seems the most likely to me. If you have a str of length `200` and an `n=200`, then both are going to do one iteration and any difference will vanish in the overhead. What happens when `l` (the `len(str)`) is very large? To do this analysis right, you should really be looking at speed compared to a ratio of `l:n`.

Comment: Not in this case.  The difference between the main string of about 4 million characters and the substrings makes the reduction in number of loops negligible.

Comment: @Evgeniy answer is a better answer after knowing the string sizes.